# Multiple invoicing for single Sales Order via Suite-script 2.0 Net-suite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Scenario is to create multiple invoices for single sales order using Suite script 2.0.

Sales order status is "PENDING BILLING" : Script triggers to create multiple invoice if this condition is true.

After creating first invoice using function record.transform() from a user event script the sales order status turns into "BILLED". After that if we again try to create an Invoice for that same sales order it will throw " error : INVALID_INITIALIZE_REF". I tried updating the "orderstatus" of Sales order from script but that was throwing "INVALID_VALUE" even though i got that value from sales order object only, before it got updated.

Is there a way to use record.transform() for creating multiple Invoices.

or Is there a way to update Sales Order status back to "PENDING BILLING" once it gets updated to "BILLED".

or Is there a way to control "orderstatus" of sales order.

Answer (score 1):

You can make more than 1 invoice per sales order if your invoice is not for the complete sales order. For instance, if the sales order had 5 line items each with a quantity of 10, you could create an invoice for only 3 of those lines, or perhaps qty 5 of each line or only 1 line. By default though, when transforming a sales order to an invoice, it will assume all lines are being invoiced so your code would need to set the qty to invoice on each line. When creating a process in code, it is best to perform the process first in the UI so that you can see how the record is going to act through the entire process.

Comment: oh okay!!! I checked when the lines are not fulfilled it is allowing me to create multiple invoices, and the sales order status remains PARTIAL FULFILLMENT.

Thanks.